# How do I configure an interface to have *both* a DHCP address and a static address in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, interface

In a lab setup, I want eth0 on a Ubuntu server box to get a DHCP address for talking to the outside world, and I also want to assign it a static 10.x.y.z address for talking to other boxes on the local network that have 10.x.y.z addresses. I want to do this by editing /etc/network/interfaces.

The man page for /etc/network/interfaces is modeled after "here's a bunch of examples, I hope you can figure out the actual rules on your own". I don't see a way to give one interface two addresses using two different methods (static and dhcp), and initial fumbling didn't produce useful results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use eth:N notation for that.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.32.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Errrr, could you say a bit more than that? I see nothing about that in the man page.

Comment: Do you see "eth0" section in config? You can add "eth0:1" section as well.

Comment: += And even "eth0:0", since it's numbered from zero.

Comment: I added an example that demonstrates what poige mentioned.  Though I have never actually used this myself.

Comment: @Zoredache, you've left no chances of discovery to Paul. :-)

Comment: I cleaned up the example a bit more to make it clear that the first entry for the interface doesn't use the : notation, but the rest do. Many thanks! It is quite sad that ":" isn't even hinted at in the man pages.

Answer (score 1):

`ip` can add multiple addresses to an interface.

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    up ip addr add 192.168.32.10/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: The question was about adding multiple methods, not just multiple addresses.

Comment: @Paul: I just tried, and it _does_ add DHCP + static to eth0.